# Simplify one row Grid Xamarin forms Xaml

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, grid

Does anyone know a simpler way to define a one row Grid. I have the following:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Text="Tester:"/>
    <Entry Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

Hard to explain but using xamStrap to layout some forms and due to the label and entry layout wrapping required we need to create Grid's currently for the label and entry pairing. Having a grid for every label and entry on the form is making some really ugly large xaml contentviews.

Is there any shorthand or better way to lay this out in xaml?

Comment: With the use of a grid, not really, at least not in XAML.  You could always generate the grid programmatically using a loop.  Alternatively, look at using a CollectionView ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/populate-data

Comment: Can't you just use a `ListView` or the Latest `CollectionView`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a horizontal `StackLayout` / `FlexLayout` instead of a Grid.
If you prefer grid, you could also convert this view to a custom control to make the code in the ContentPage shorter.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using [BindableLayouts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/bindable-layouts) to simplify your XAML.

As for the elements, you can achieve with Grid or StackLayout.
I would prefer using the Grid, since you have more control over the size of the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Grid supports arranging views into rows and columns:

```
    <Grid>


        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="150" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

         <Label
            Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Text="Test"
            TextColor="White"
            VerticalTextAlignment="End" />

         </Grid>
```